# Custom web part saves custom field results in project out of date error

Tags: web-part, project-server

We've created a webpart and user control that uses a sharepoint people picker to save AD accounts to a project custom field.

To save, we've hooked into the ProjectSave event (click 'Save' on the ribbon) using a page component.

After the save callback is triggered and we've updated the custom field, PWA complains that, "the project is out of date" and has been, "updated in another session."  That's obviously our doing.

Our suspicion is that someone tracks the last updated date/time and notices that it's changed since being created.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Update**

```
void OnSaveProject()
    {
        ProjectDataSet projectDataSet = ProjWeb.project.ReadProjectEntities(ProjectUid, (int)(ProjectEntityType.ProjectCustomFields | ProjectEntityType.Project), SvcProject.DataStoreEnum.PublishedStore);
        //ProjectDataSet projectDataSet = ProjWeb.project.ReadProject(ProjectUid, SvcProject.DataStoreEnum.PublishedStore);
        ProjectDataSet.ProjectRow project = projectDataSet.Project[0];

        if (!project.IsPROJ_CHECKOUTBYNull() && project.PROJ_SESSION_UID != null)
        {
            Guid fieldGuid;                

            // skip if this customfield is not set
            //
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProjectServerCustomFieldAccounts))
            {
                fieldGuid = ProjWeb.customFields.GetCustomField(ProjectServerCustomFieldAccounts);

                if (!ProjWeb.SetCustomValue(projectDataSet, project.PROJ_SESSION_UID, fieldGuid, PeopleEditor.CommaSeparatedAccounts))
                {
                    PpWebPart.Log("Error at SetCustomValue to value" + PeopleEditor.CommaSeparatedAccounts);
                }
           }
        }
```

Then, SetCustomValue:

```
public bool SetCustomValue(SvcProject.ProjectDataSet forProject, Guid sessionUId, Guid field, String value)
    {
        Guid ciJobId = Guid.NewGuid();

        foreach (SvcProject.ProjectDataSet.ProjectCustomFieldsRow r in forProject.ProjectCustomFields)
        {
            if (r.MD_PROP_UID.Equals(field))
            {
                if (r.TEXT_VALUE.Equals(value)) return false;
                r.TEXT_VALUE = value;

                project.QueueUpdateProject(ciJobId, sessionUId, forProject, false);
                queueSystem.WaitFor(ciJobId);

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your custom Save logic isn't calling Update().  If it is, then what is happening is that the page is attempting to save from the known state 'XYZ', hits your Update() which then changes the underlying item from 'XYZ' into state 'ABC'. However, the Update() from the submit itself hasn't fired yet.  When it does, it is expecting to update item in state 'XYZ' but instead finds state 'ABC'.  To the code, this means that the underlying item has been changed which means that the changes being submitted contain outdated data along with the updates.  SharePoint fails the second update in order to prevent data loss.

Comment: OK.  If we don't call update, will the changes persist in the data set until the submit calls Update()?

Comment: I can't really answer that without knowing the code, however, if the fields you need saved are in the page being submitted then they will be saved

Comment: The fields themselves are not on the PDP.  The idea is to have the people editor/web part handle selecting accounts and to save to a project custom field.  Ideally the custom field would not need to be on the PDP.

Comment: Which Update do you mean?  PSI.project.QueueUpdateProject?

Comment: Then you might need to hook into a later event in order to do your Update or possibly move this functionality to an EventReceiver

Comment: I am referring to whichever.UpdateNNN() method is being called.  It is hard to be more specific without the actual code

Comment: Are you familiar with other events that are triggered in addition to 'SaveProject' when clicking 'Save' on the ribbon?

Comment: I've added some code to the question, if you wouldn't mind having a look.

Comment: if there is a base.ProjectSave() (or a similar line in the ProjectSave() method), then that needs to happen before you call your custom code.  Beyond that, it appears that the object model follows the 'ing' and 'ed' standard for events - that is, you would have to hook into the 'ProjectSaved' event rather than the 'ProjectSaving' as 'ProjectSaved' happens after the internal update has taken place.

Comment: The command that the page component registers with is 'ProjectSave'.  It's not clear that there would be a 'ProjectSaved' command as well.  And sadly the callback method that is triggered is on a bit of an Island (there's no base class to speak of).

Comment: Without a deeper knowledge of how this all ties together, all I can suggest is a kludge: putting the custom code in a event later in the life cycle (like PreRender) that will run the custom code if a save just happened (determined by setting a flag in ProjectSave).  This is horribly clumsy though.